# J-Meter Not Accessing Bean

Tags: java, post, jmeter, javabeans

In my `Controller` java class I have the following lines:

```
CartBean cart = (CartBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
int selection = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("choice"));
ArrayList<RoomDTO> booking = cart.getSearch().getResults().get(selection);
```

When I use `JMeter` and run a query, I am receiving a `NullPointerException` at the 3rd line.

The `jsp` page that calls the `Controller` simply contains rooms that can be selected and hence my HTTP Request is just (from JMeter):

```
POST data:
action=Checkout&choice=6
```

In `JMeter`, I added a `HTTP Cookie Manager` and when I run the requests, a `cookie` is being saved:

```
Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=7886784BB8E29BB9AA16564E53623166
```

Would anyone have any idea what the problem might be? If I run the program in Eclipse, there is no issue...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code

```
cart.getSearch().getResults().get(selection);
```

the NPE could be caused by

1. cart being null
2. cart.getSearch() returning null
3. cart.getSearch().getResults() returning null

before assuming that calling this code from jmeter is causing the problem determine which one is causing the problem

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Turns out it was an issue related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have some comments on your problem,

`request.getParameter("choice")` will get the value from the submitted form with the input type named choice. So `request.getParameter()` will retrieve a value that the client has submitted either through POST Or GET methods.

Now for `request.getAttribute()`, this is all done server side. you add the attribute to the request and you submit the request to another resource, the client does not know about this. So all the code handling this would typically be in servlets.

You cannot set **`Cart Bean`** values using `request.setattribute()` with **Jmeter**, as you may have done using JSP pages in your webapp. Jmeter can send POST/GET methods with different content type and header values.

**Error in 3rd line:** `CartBean cart = (CartBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("cart");` 
perform null check before proceeding for both **cart object** and `request.getParameter("choice")`

```
if(cart==null){//do action} 
if(request.getParameter("choice")==null){//do action}
```

One more point ,
I think , It is best use  Test Script Recorder to create Test Plan and then Correlate variables.

gud luck.. :)